# How to login to MySQL / MariaDB using Ansible?

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am using Ansible to replicate a given shopware installation guide with an Ansible project. Therefore I need to create a database and edit privileges.

I added my credentials to local `my.cnf` file and copy it to the server via

```yaml
- name: Create Database
  become: yes
  community.mysql.mysql_db:
    name: shopware
    state: present
    config_file: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

```
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
[client]
user="root"
password=""
```

The next step

```yaml
- name: Create Database
  become: yes
  community.mysql.mysql_db:
    name: shopware
    state: present
    config_file: /etc/mysql/my.cnf

- name: Create user with password, all database privileges and 'WITH GRANT OPTION' shopware database
  become: yes
  community.mysql.mysql_user:
    state: present
    name: "{{shopware_db_username}}"
    password: "{{shopware_db_pass}}"
    priv:
      'shopware.*': 'ALL,GRANT'
```

is throwing the error:

```
TASK [Create Database] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [swserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /etc/mysql/my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1698, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'\")"}
```

**Additional info**

- login via `mysql -u root -p` with empty password does not work

**Server**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 5.4.0-94-generic

**Host**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64
- Ansible 2.9.6
- Kernel: 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2

Source:
https://git.rosibert.de/rpolito/ansible-shopware

Comment: if `mysql -u root -p` with an empty password does not work, then perhaps someone has set a password, or otherwise configured root to not be allowed to log in ?

Comment: I tired the same with password="1" and this did not work either. It's a default installation of mariadb with apt. nothing configured except the my.cnf posted

Comment: run https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_secure_installation/ and configure your system, before using it

Answer (score 0):

Since I had a similar question in the past I like to share my solution approach here.

After MySQL/MariaDB server installation

```yaml
- name: Install from EPEL-7 and/or IUS-7 repositories
  yum:
    name: ['mariadb103-server', 'mariadb103', 'python2-PyMySQL']
    state: latest
```

and copying the config to `/etc/my.cnf.d/my.cnf`

```ini
[server]

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/data
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
```

it was possible to start the service

```yaml
- name: Make sure service is started and enabled
  systemd:
    name: mariadb
    state: started
    enabled: yes
```

and connect to via socket to perform the next steps

```yaml
  # mysql_secure_installation
 
- name: Delete all anonymous SQL user accounts
  mysql_user:
    user: "" 
    host_all: yes
    state: absent

- name: Remove the SQL test database
  mysql_db:
    db: "test"
    state: absent

- name: Change root user password on first run
  mysql_user: 
    login_user: root
    login_password: ''
    name: root
    password: "{{ SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }}"
    priv: "*.*:ALL,GRANT"
    host: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    - "127.0.0.1"
    - "::1"
    - "localhost"
```

After that, tasks like

```yaml
  - name: Make sure user exists
    shell:
      cmd: "mysql -uroot -p{{ SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD }} -e\"CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS '{{ SQL_USER }}'@'{{ SQL_IP }}' IDENTIFIED BY '{{ SQL_USER_PASSWORD }}' REQUIRE SSL;\" -N -B"
    register: result
```

were be possible.

Comment: that did not work :(

Comment: @R.Polito, I think much more information about your environment will be necessary. In example, who is making from where a connection, to which service and where, what are the error messages, etc. Maybe you can edit your initial question and make your case more clear.

Comment: It's the same error msg as I posted initially. I added my git repo so you can check it out and play around with it. Excecuting it from wsl Ubuntu to Ubuntu VM

Comment: @R.Polito, the initial provided error message says "_check `login_user` and `login_password` are correct ... Access denied for user `'root'@'localhost'`_". This indicates that you haven't configured your database server correctly yet as already mentioned within other comments.

Comment: I know but my question is how do i set the password for my root user without being able to login? I can go in via sudo and do so manually but what do I need ansible for then?!

Comment: @R.Polito, I don't get this comment "_How do I set the password for my `root` user without being able to login? I can go in via `sudo` and do so manually_" as the two statement exclude each other for me. As already mentioned, I think much more information about your environment will be necessary. In example, who is making from where a connection, to which service and where, what are the error messages, etc. Maybe you can edit your initial question and make your case more clear.